# ReactJS - Remove selected item when two react-select use one data option source only

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have two react-select is select for `approver` and select for `group-owner`.

Options data for two react-select will load from 1 data source.

```
[
  {value: 1, label: 'Nguyen Van A'},
  {value: 2, label: 'Nguyen Van B'},
  {value: 3, label: 'Nguyen Van C'},
  {value: 4, label: 'Nguyen Van D'},
  {value: 5, label: 'Nguyen Van E'},
  {value: 6, label: 'Nguyen Van F'},
]
```

I want, when I choose `group-owner` select, the item selected will remove in the `group-owner` option list and in the `approver` option list. And vice versa too.

When I clear all the options, the option lists of `group-owner` and `approver` are back to the way they were.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below coded can solved problems

```
useEffect(() => {
    const data = [...selectedOwner, ...selectedApprover];
    setListCanSelect(listTemp);
    data.map(item => {
      setListCanSelect(prev => prev.filter(i => parseInt(i.value) !== item));
    });
  }, [selectedOwner, selectedApprover]);
```

Comment: what's `listTemp` and why do we need to re-set the list per every item? why not reconstruct the entire list and set it only once at the end?